# Is possible to show a dialog before show Recents, Press Back or Home Button?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to detect when the user click on `BackPressed` (this I can override the `onBackPressed()`) also the home button and the recent button.

My goal is, don't quit the app until the user Accepts a dialog, I mean, for instance I'm using an app, that doesn't let go to another app to see something, so I want to do something like a "Security thingy".

Scenario would be :

1. User is watching a video (that's an example)
2. User tries to press the square button to show recent apps
3. Then user sees a dialog saying if you leave you are gonna loose the video (whatever...) if he press yes do the normal stuff like see the recents if he presses no, don't show recents...
4. The same with the home button

I've already tried `onPause()` but the thing is that I see the dialog after the action is done and if I do an if condition it crashes because it needs the `super.onPause()`.

Any clue how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only can handle the back button. For back button, you can override the `onBackPressed()` method of your Activity and show the user a dialog and then call  `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` when the user clicks on Yes button of your dialog

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     //show dialog
}

private void onDialogYesButtonClick() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
}
```

Comment: Well I know this, but the other ones?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can handle other buttons, it is better to save the video time in onPause() method and retrieve it when the user comes back to the app. For saving time you can use ViewModel or savedInstanceState bundle.

Comment: Well I'm doing like a test, so I don't want the user go to other app, but perhaps... this is a good option, that if you leave the activity I store that user left, but the thing is... if he did accidentally? I want to do it fair and maybe I can do a timer to say if user is out of the screen for X seconds put the sharedpreference stuff

Comment: Could you make an example of what I said and I'll mark your answer as a correct?

Comment: You can simply save video state in the SharedPrefrences in the onPause() method, and retrieve it in the onResume() method. You don't need any timer.

Comment: It's not a video.... Let's say it's an exam, and I don't want user go out of the test.... so I want to detect if user goes away or not... that's why I need a timer because MAYBE user can press with any bad intention and then come back to the app....